# Python 3.6 Tkinter and Multiprocessing

Tags: python, multithreading, ssh, tkinter, multiprocessing

Some backstory, this application reaches out to 45+ devices and performs some SSH commands through Netmiko.  It's two GUI windows. The first asks your Username/PW and for specific input by the user.  After submitting this, another GUI window pops up with a button.  This button when selected runs the commands of a function.  I've setup a GUI to make it pretty user friendly to hopefully allow our HelpDesk to utilize it.

I've got it to work, but it takes upwards of 10 minutes to complete 45 SSH sessions to the devices.  I started researching some ways to multi-thread or multi-process but have not been able to get them to work.

Any help would be much appreciated to get multi-processing/threading to cut the processing time down.  The goal would be to have 5 to 10 of the SSH sessions going at once to help limit the amount of time waiting on the application.  Also possibly stopping the second GUI window from freezing while the process is in action.

Below is the working code that takes upwards of 10 minutes to complete.  I import "a_devices" from a separate python file just a FYI.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import netmiko
import sys
import os
from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import ttk
import threading
from multiprocessing import Process
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time
import getpass
from Dictionaries import *
from netmiko.ssh_exception import NetMikoTimeoutException, NetMikoAuthenticationException
from paramiko.ssh_exception import SSHException
from datetime import datetime

vpntermination = None

username = input('Username: ')
password = getpass.win_getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None)

# Sends outputs to Text widgets
class StdoutRedirector(object):
  def __init__(self,text_widget):
    self.text_space = text_widget
  def write(self,string):
    self.text_space.insert('end', string)
    self.text_space.see('end')

class Input_Window_GUI():
  def __init__(self, master): 
    self.master = master
    master.wm_title("VPN Termination Application")
    self.label = Label(master, text="User to be terminated:", font=24).grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
    self.master.geometry("650x600")
    self.master.lift()
    self.master.attributes('-topmost',True)
    self.master.after_idle(master.attributes,'-topmost',False)
    self.master.grid_columnconfigure(3, minsize=250, weight=1)

    self.textBoxFrame = tkinter.Frame(master)
    self.textBoxFrame.grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky=E+W)

    self.textbox=Text(self.textBoxFrame)
    self.textbox.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=W, pady=2)

    sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector(self.textbox)

    self.e1 = Entry(self.master)
    self.e1.insert(10,"")
    self.e1.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=2)

    self.submitButtonFrame = tkinter.Frame(master)
    self.addButtonFrame = tkinter.Frame(master)
    self.clearButtonFrame = tkinter.Frame(master)
    self.submitButtonFrame.grid(row=6, column=1, columnspan=1)
    self.addButtonFrame.grid(row=2, column=3, columnspan=1)
    self.clearButtonFrame.grid(row=2, column=4, columnspan=1)

    self.buttonFrameClose = tkinter.Frame(master)
    self.buttonFrameClose.grid(row=6, column=4)

    self.submit_button = Button(self.submitButtonFrame, text='Submit Changes', command=self.Submit_Application, height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=2)
    self.add_user_button = Button(self.addButtonFrame, text='Add User for Termination', command=self.Add_User, height = 3, width = 25).grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W, pady=2)
    self.close_app_button = Button(self.buttonFrameClose, text='Close App', command=self.Close_All, height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=6, column=3, sticky=E, pady=2)
    self.clear_user_button = Button(self.clearButtonFrame, text='Clear All', command=self.Clear_User, height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=W, pady=2)


  def Add_User(self):
    try:
        if not self.e1.get():# empty! (empty string is false value)
            print('Ooops, nothing entered, please enter an acceptible username.')
        elif self.e1.get() == " ":
            print('Ooops, nothing entered, please enter an acceptible username.')
            e1.delete(0,END)
        else:
            user = self.e1.get()
            global vpntermination #Had to change to global so it could be passed throughout the multiple windows.
            vpntermination = user
            print("User staged for Termination: %s" % (user))
            print("")
            self.e1.delete(0,END)
            return vpntermination
    except ValueError:
      print('Incorrect entry, please reenter username.')
      self.e1.delete(0,END)
      return 'Value'    
    except TypeError:
      print('Incorrect entry, please reenter username.')
      self.e1.delete(0,END)
      return 'Type'

  def Clear_User(self):
    vpntermination = None
    print("User cleared, readd User.")
    print("")

  def Close_All(self):
    self.master.destroy()
    sys.exit(1)

  #Closes initial tkinter window and continues the code. 
  def Submit_Application(self):
    self.master.after(1000, lambda: self.master.destroy())

class Output_Window_GUI:
  def __init__(self, root):
    self.root = root
    root.wm_title("VPN Termination Output")
    self.label = Label(root, text="Output:", font=24).grid(row=0, column=2, columnspan=2)
    self.root.geometry("650x600")
    self.root.lift()
    self.root.attributes('-topmost',True)
    self.root.after_idle(root.attributes,'-topmost',False)

    self.textBoxFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    self.textBoxFrame.grid(row=5, column=3, columnspan=1, sticky=E+W)

    self.textbox=Text(self.textBoxFrame)
    self.textbox.grid(row=5, column=3, sticky=W, pady=2)

    #Calls the class to send CLI output to Textbox
    sys.stdout = StdoutRedirector(self.textbox)

    self.buttonFrameClose = tkinter.Frame(root)
    self.buttonFrameClose.grid(row=6, column=3)
    self.buttonFrame = tkinter.Frame(root)
    self.buttonFrame.grid(row=2, column=2, columnspan=3)
    self.close_all_button = Button(self.buttonFrameClose, text='Close App', command=self.Close_All, height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)
    self.start_button = Button(self.buttonFrame, text='Send Commands', command=self.Start_Commands, height = 3, width = 15).grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=W, pady=4)

  def task():
    root.after(2000, task)

  def Close_All(self):
    self.root.destroy()
    sys.exit(1)

  def Start_Commands(self):
    print('VPN Termination Commands are in process for User: ' + vpntermination +'....please wait.')
    print('')
    start_time = datetime.now()
    for a_device in all_firewalls:
      per_fw_start_time = datetime.now()
      try:
        net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
        hostname = net_connect.send_command("show hostname") #Used to store Hostname.
        output = net_connect.send_command("vpn-sessiondb logoff name " + str(vpntermination) +  " noconfirm") #Used for vpn termination command.
        print('\n******* Output for device ' + hostname + ' *******' )
        print(output)
        print('')
        per_fw_end_time = datetime.now()
        per_fw_total_time = per_fw_end_time - per_fw_start_time
        print("******* " + hostname + " {0} *******".format(a_device['ip'])+ " took " + str(per_fw_total_time) + " to process.")
        print('')
        net_connect.disconnect() #Hoping to speed up process time within multi-threading issues.
      except (NetMikoTimeoutException, NetMikoAuthenticationException) as e: #Handles timeout errors.
        print("Could not connect to {}, due to {}", e)
        print('')

    end_time = datetime.now()
    total_time = end_time - start_time
    print('\nTotal process time: ' + str(total_time))

def main():

  #tkinter GUI that adds user for termination.
  master = Tk()
  my_gui = Input_Window_GUI(master)
  master.mainloop()  

  #tkinter GUI that starts the user being terminated on all devices.
  root=Tk()
  out_gui = Output_Window_GUI(root)
  root.mainloop()


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is create a `multiprocessing.Queue` as a global variable and a separate process using `multiprocessing.Popen` *before* running the `mainloop`.

The function that you use in `Popen` (which is run in a separate process) should wait for messages on the `Queue` and act on them. This process does the real work.

Meanwhile the GUI feeds commands (e.g. a 2-tuple of command and username such as `('delete', 'foo@bar')`) to delete a user) and data into the `Queue` based on user input. It should also use an `after` callback to query the queue and process any responses from the other process.

Some notes on style.

- It is conventional in Python to start class names with an uppercase letter. Function and method names should be lower case. See [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).
- Since you are running a GUI, it would be better style to use [message boxes](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/tk_messagebox.htm) to inform the user about errors instead of print statements. Depending on the OS and how the program is started the user might or might not see the printed output.
- It is generally not considered good practice to use `from <module> import *`. In this case I would suggest `import tkinter as tk`.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much for your response. If possible, could you show me how to implement that within my code as I'm using two classes for the GUI...and a button activates my function (start_commands) for the SSH processes, which has an arugment in a dictionary format.  Note:  I've edited my original code with your style suggestions (thanks!).

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So I was able to get the processing working thanks to some online articles and Roland Smith.  Unfortunately to get it to work with tkinter, I had to remove the button that sends the function for the user and just have it automatically perform it between GUI's.

Currently the username/password are not passing, I know for them to pass I probably need to put them in the Process args part of my loop so they're passed to each Process (which I haven't tested yet).

**I could use some more direction on getting Queuing stood up within my for loop, and passing anything that happens within the processes to my final output GUI (root).**

```
def start_commands(vpntermination, a_device):
  print('VPN Termination Commands are in process for User: ' + str(vpntermination) +'....please wait.')
  print('')
  start_time = datetime.now()
  for a_device in all_firewalls: #Maybe add threading/processing into the for loop?
    per_fw_start_time = datetime.now()
    try:
      net_connect = ConnectHandler(**a_device)
      hostname = net_connect.send_command("show hostname") #Used to store Hostname.
      output = net_connect.send_command("vpn-sessiondb logoff name " + str(vpntermination) +  " noconfirm") #Used for vpn termination command.
      print('\n******* Output for device ' + hostname + ' *******' )
      print(output)
      print('')
      per_fw_end_time = datetime.now()
      per_fw_total_time = per_fw_end_time - per_fw_start_time
      print("******* " + hostname + " {0} *******".format(a_device['ip'])+ " took " + str(per_fw_total_time) + " to process.")
      print('')
      net_connect.disconnect() #Hoping to speed up process time within multi-threading issues.
    except (NetMikoTimeoutException, NetMikoAuthenticationException) as e: #Handles timeout errors.
      print("Could not connect to {}, due to {}", e)
      print('')
      net_connect.disconnect() # Disconnect session if exception is thrown

  end_time = datetime.now()
  total_time = end_time - start_time
  print('\nTotal process time: ' + str(total_time))


def main():
  username = input('Username: ')
  password = getpass.win_getpass(prompt='Password: ', stream=None)

  #tkinter GUI that adds user for termination.
  master = Tk()
  my_gui = InputWindowGUI(master)
  master.mainloop() 

#Move the loops below root tkinter and reenable the stdredirector.
  procs = []
  for a_device in all_firewalls:
    print(a_device)
    print(vpntermination)
    my_proc = Process(target=start_commands, args=(a_device, vpntermination))
    my_proc.start()
    procs.append(my_proc)

  for a_proc in procs:
    print (a_proc)
    a_proc.join()

  #tkinter GUI that starts the user being terminated on all VCs.
  root=Tk()
  out_gui = OutputWindowGUI(root)
  root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```